# How to detect single characters in a diagram

Tags: c#, tesseract

I have a diagram which contains a line and labels. I want to use Tesseract OCR to detect the position of the labels A,B,C,D,E

https://ibb.co/eEQWxS (I'm new to S.O. so cannot post image)

Here's my code:

```
var testImagePath = @"test.png";

using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube))
{
    engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDE");
    engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleBlock;

    using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(testImagePath))
    {
        using (var page = engine.Process(img))
        {
            var text = page.GetHOCRText(0);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, Tesseract gets confused by the line. Is there a way to ignore the line and just extract the letters?

Comment: Are the positions of the letters fixed? I.e. if I were to crop the image to each letter's position in your example image, would that same position work for all images you intend to process?

Comment: No, the idea of the project is to detect all the labels and find their positions. Later, the ABCDE... will be replaced with dimension integers.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a simple fix for that. It makes sense for Tesseract to evaluate everything it sees, including the lines. How would you expect Tesseract to ignore the line and focus on the letters if you can't conclusively specify the position of the line or letters? If there was a way to distinguish the line from the letters (e.g. different color), you could preprocess the image (turn pixels with the line color to white); but I assume that's not a workable solution?

Comment: Thanks for your help Flater. I'm going to try something like that, filter out the line so Tesseract can focus on the labels only.